# Find an equation in rectangular coordinates for the surface represented by the cylindrical equation

Tags: calculus, rectangles, cylindrical-coordinates

The given is $$r=6\sin(\theta)$$
Multiplying both sides by $r$ yields
$$r^2=6r\sin(\theta)$$
It follows such that
$$r^2=6y$$
$$x^2+y^2=6y$$
$$x^2+y^2-6y=0$$
Completing the square
$$x^2+y^2-6y+36-36=0$$
$$x^2+(y-6)^2=36$$
I followed the text book example bout the answer isn't correct. I might have messed up with completing the square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete the square you want to write
$$
x^2+y^2-6y+9 - 9 = x^2+(y-3)^2 - 9
$$
since $(y-3)^2=y^2-6y+9$.